# Checking if a number is NaN fails

Tags: c++

Given the following questions [Divide by Zero Prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299992/divide-by-zero-prevention) and [Check if it's a NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437085/check-nan-number) as the examples I've written the folowing code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
bool IsNonNan( float fVal )
{ 
     return( fVal == fVal );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nQuota = 0;
    float fZero = 3 / (float)nQuota; 
    cout << fZero << endl;
    cout << IsNonNan( fZero ) << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Why is `IsNonNan` returning true? also why would `int nZero = 3 / (float)nQuota;` output: `-2147483648`?

Comment: You could use the standard `isnan()` function, declared in `<cmath>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not, is not, NaN states for "Not a Number", it means, something that can't be expressed as a number (indeterminations like `0 / 0` which mathematically speaking, don't have a numeric representation), infinity, is just that, infinities, positive or negative

To check if a float is infinity, you can use:

```
inline bool IsInf(float fval)  {
    return (fval == fval) && ((fval - fval) != 0.0f);
}
```

Comment: To check for infinity, one should use `std::isinf` from `<cmath>`. The rest of your answer is mathematically unsound; infinity is not a number either in standard analysis.

Comment: Yes, indeed (although I'm suspecting that (s?)he's leaning to implement it by h(im|er)self)

Answer (score 2):

`3 / 0` is `+INF`, not `NaN`.  Try `0 / 0`.

Comment: But isn't #.INF a NaN? If it's not a NaN, how to check if a number is `pos inf` or `neg inf`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c Related.

Answer (score 0):

`int nZero = 3 / (float)nQuota;` outputs `-2147483648` because the conversion of `0` to `float` is value of <= `1e-009` which is given throughout `float f = 0.000000001;` or less.