# The try() and catch() are not working; The program crashes and never executes the catch() block

Tags: c++, try-catch, crash-reports

I am trying to use the exceptions catching mechanism on a simple piece of C++ code that does on purpose a division by 0:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int DefaultSize = 10;

int main()
{
int top = 90;
int bottom = 0;
cout << "top / 2 = " << (top/ 2) << endl;
cout << "top / 3 = " << (top/ 3) << endl;

try
{
cout << "top divided by bottom = ";
cout << (top / bottom) << endl;
}
catch(...)
{
cout << "something has gone wrong!" << endl;
}
cout << "Done." << endl;
return 0;
}
```

The program crashes and doesn't execute the catch block - In Eclipse I am getting a standard error:
*0 [main] CPP166 8964 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to CPP166.exe.stackdump*.
Run the program in another IDE NetBeans and have done multiple clen and re-built with no positive results.
Please help I have looked at the related answers but I cannot identify the problem.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299992/divide-by-zero-prevention

Answer (score 2):

Division by zero is *not* one of the events that raises an exception in C++.

The exceptions listed in the ISO standard are:

```
namespace std {
    class logic_error;
        class domain_error;
        class invalid_argument;
        class length_error;
        class out_of_range;
    class runtime_error;
        class range_error;
        class overflow_error;
        class underflow_error;
}
```

and you would think that `overflow_error` would be ideal for indicating a divide by zero.

But `C++03` and `C++11` section `5.6 /4` specifically state:

> If the second operand of `/` or `%` is zero, the behavior is undefined.

If you *want* an exception, you will have to code it yourself, with something like:

```
#include <stdexcept>

inline int intDiv (int num, int denom) {
    if (denom == 0) throw std::overflow_error("DivByZero");
    return num / denom;
}
```

and convert your calls from:

```
cout << (top / bottom) << endl;
```

to:

```
cout << intDiv(top, bottom) << endl;
```

Comment: PK that makes sense so I need to built a function checking for the divider being 0 if it returns "true" then the code may work.

Comment: In last statement, Only closing parenthesis? Is it by mistake?

Comment: @pranitkothari: mistake. Fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again this is really a working solution - never thought that division by 0 is not an exception in C/C++ - my bad.